# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent only on page refresh

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, http-headers

I have this problem  only when I try refresh the page and I can not solve it, I tried everything but still happens the same. It began to happen when I add socket.io at the project. The project run in several servers which are connected one each other throught sockets.

TEST CASES: When I render the page, at the first time everything goes well but, if I refresh the same page, I get this error:

ERROR: "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)"

ATTENTION: when get in IF() and send "return res.end('The Activation Code is INVALID!');" it DOESN'T HAPPEND! I refresh it and refresh it and everything goes well. My problem is in the RENDER.

MY CODE BELOW:

```
activationUser = function(req,res,next){
        var data = {
            activationCode : req.params.activationCode,
            now : new Date().valueOf(),
            ip : req.connection.remoteAddress,
            fId : frontalId
        }
        socketCore.emit('activationUser', data);
        socketCore.on(frontalId + 'activationUserResp', function(data){
            if(data.msg == "CHECKED!"){
                next();
            }else{
                return res.end(data.msg);
            }
        });
    }

router.get('/activationUser/:activationCode',activationUser,function(req,res){
    var data = {
        activationCode : req.params.activationCode,
        fId : frontalId
    }
    socketCore.emit('step2', data);
    socketCore.on(frontalId + 'step2Resp', function(data){
        if(data.msg == 'err'){
            return res.end('The Activation Code is INVALID!');
        }else{
            return res.render('registro2', {title: 'title | '+ data.name + ' ' + data.lastname, user:data});
        }
    }); 
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The particular error you are getting happens when you try to send anything on the `res` object after the complete response has already been sent.  This often occurs because of errors in asynchronous logic.  In your particular case, it apepars to be because you are assigning a new event handler with `socketCore.on()` every single time the router is hit.  Those event handlers will accumulate and after the first time the route is hit, they will execute multiple times triggering the sending of multiple responses on the same response object, thus trigger that error.

The main ways to fix your particular problem are:

1. Use `.once()` instead of `.on()` so the event handler automatically removes itself after being triggered.
2. Manually remove the `.on()` event handler after you get the response.
3. Move the event handler outside of the route so it's only ever installed once.

In your particular case, since `socketCore` is a shared object available to all requests, it appears that you also have a race condition.  If multiple users trigger the `'/activationUser/:activationCode'` route in the same general time frame, then you will register two event handlers with `socketCore.on()` (one for each route that is hit) and you will do two `socketCore.emit('step2', data);`.  But, you have no way of associating which response belongs with which request and the two responses could easily get mixed up - going to the wrong request.

This highlights how socket.io connections are not request/response.  They are message/answer, but unless you manually code a correspondence between a specific message request and a specific answer, there is no way to correlate which goes with which.  So, without assigning some particular responseID that lets you know which response belongs to which message, you can't use a socket.io connection like this in a multi-user environment.  It will just cause race conditions.  It's actually simpler to use an HTTP request/response for this type of data fetching because each response goes only with the request that made it in the HTTP architecture.

You can change your architecture for making the socketCore request, but you will have to manually assign an ID to each request and make sure the server is sending back that ID with the response that belongs to that request.  Then, you can write a few lines of code on the receiving side of things that will make sure the right response gets fed to the code with the matching request.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

I have not tried yet your recommendation but it make sense so, I will try later and I'll tell you how it work, just to confirm because I know it is the right solution.

About what you tell me about the information consistency, this is something I have been weighing heavily during the last few nights. I was thinking to generate them an identifier to each message but I think this will complicate the code. I chose to use sockets because it seems faster and lighter when communicating information but I am new in node and I would like to know your opinion.